# How to stop marquee slide show on mouse over in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I want to stop slide show on mouse over and start on mouse out. 
I saw some suggestions in stack overflow.  
In that i didn't get any solution (may be this is my fault to understand the others code according to my code. So because of that i am giving my code).

```
<marquee height="80%" width="600px" direction="left" scrolldelay="120" align="middle">
<div class="itemMar"><img src="http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/storymaker-best-hubble-space-telescope-images-20092-514x268.jpg" width="120px" height="120px" border="5"/><br /><p style="text-align: center;">name</p><p style="text-align: center;">0123456789</p><p style="text-align: center;">ssc</p>
    </div>
  <div class="itemMar"><img src="http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/storymaker-best-hubble-space-telescope-images-20092-514x268.jpg" width="120px" height="120px" border="5"/><br /><p style="text-align: center;">name</p><p style="text-align: center;">0123456789</p><p style="text-align: center;">ssc</p>
    </div>
  <div class="itemMar"><img src="http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/storymaker-best-hubble-space-telescope-images-20092-514x268.jpg" width="120px" height="120px" border="5"/><br /><p style="text-align: center;">name</p ><p style="text-align: center;">0123456789</p><p style="text-align: center;">ssc</p>
    </div>
  <div class="itemMar"><img src="http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/storymaker-best-hubble-space-telescope-images-20092-514x268.jpg" width="120px" height="120px" border="5"/><br /><p style="text-align: center;">name</p ><p style="text-align: center;">0123456789</p><p style="text-align: center;">ssc</p>
    </div>

        </marquee>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" onmousedown="this.stop();" onmouseup="this.start();"></marquee>

<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();"></marquee>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" 
         direction="left"
         onmouseover="this.stop();"
         onmouseout="this.start();">Go on... hover over me!</marquee>
```

see your live [<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/xABM2/)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write your JavaScript inline, you can put this in a JavaScript file:

```
marquee = document.getElementsByTagName('marquee')[0];
marquee.onmouseover = function(){
  this.stop();
}
marquee.onmouseout = function(){
  this.start();
}
```

Here's a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/8fymm/1/